# Why is the WSL rootfs no longer published in the latest cloud images?

Tags: 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cloud, release-management, 22.10

I just noticed, at least for Ubuntu Jammy (22.04) that `ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz` is no longer published in the latest releases of the [Ubuntu cloud images](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/jammy/). It can be found in the [2022-09-23](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/jammy/release-20220923/) release, but is not available in releases including and after the [2022-10-11](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/jammy/release-20221011/) release. The dates appear to align with the release of Ubuntu Kinetic (22.10), which has no WSL rootfs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has WSL tar gz been removed from Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439745/has-wsl-tar-gz-been-removed-from-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-releases)

Comment: Yes, thank you! Weird, it looks like I had asked the question first!

Comment: @scottwillmoore Yeah, you did ask it first.  And I had asked for the other one to be closed as the duplicate (and the answer moved here) since both your questions are pretty much equivalent quality, IMHO.  Unfortunately, a Mod chose the other one for some reason - Perhaps because they felt it was higher quality (more detailed, longer) or because the answer was posted on it first.  On the bright side, I'm happy to see that you've received a few good upvotes/rep for asking the question - It was a good one!