# Has the WSL rootfs (.tar.gz) been removed from Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Releases website?

Tags: windows, 22.04, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

It looks like the WSL tarball of Ubuntu 22.04 has been pulled from the Ubuntu release location. It no longer appears at https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/jammy/release/.  Normally, in the past, it would have been `ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz`.

I have a [gist that helped show how to setup everything via PowerShell](https://gist.github.com/ScriptAutomate/f94cd44dacd0f420fae65414e717212d), which would include pulling down the WSL image, but it stopped working as expected for 22.04.

It looks like people can only do so now for 20.04, as that version of the `*-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz` is still available:

- https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/release/ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz

Anyone have details of why it was pulled, and if it now is meant to exist somewhere else? It was there previously, so the gist was helpful for people in getting things setup. I can update it with the new location if there is now some kind of dedicated location for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the location has changed here:
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/wsl/

You can see kinetic is there as well. This is where it is going to live from now on.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1439715/1165986) that was asked 3 hours before it.  I think it's fair to close this one as a dupe of the other, but would you create your answer on the first-asked question as well?  Thanks!

Comment: Just to follow up, why is there on link to the `wsl` folder on the [cloud images index](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/)?

Comment: That was not intended. It is fixed now.

Comment: Was this changed discussed anywhere public? Is there a reason why the new location only has daily images?